# Hibernate OneToOne joined with unique but not primary key

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, one-to-one

I have two tables:

> 1. users:
>
>    - user_id (primary)
>    - etc ..
> 2. users_info
>
>    - id (primary)
>    - user_id (unique)
>    - etc ..

I would like to create a oneToOne relationship from `user` to `user_info` on the `user_id` field. Note, that it is unique but not primary.
Can it be done on Hibernate? What ever I am doing, Hibernate try to use the `users_info.id` field instead of u`sers_info.user_id` field.

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy="user_id", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, optional=true)
@JoinColumn (name="user_id")    
public UserInfo getUserInfo() { return userInfo; }
public void setUserInfo(UserInfo userInfo) { this.userInfo = userInfo; }
private UserInfo userInfo;
```

Answer (score 3):

In `User` you should have:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy="user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, optional=true)
public UserInfo getUserInfo() { return userInfo; }
```

And in `UserInfo`:

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="user_id")
public User getUser() { return user; }
```

Have a look [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-association). It's the second example of one-to-one mapping.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you want a "unique" key that's a 1-1 mapping AND a surrogate ID? It's redundant. Just make the two PKs equal as it is a 1-1 mapping.

Comment: while I agree with you I had a client dictate this `requirement` for me and had to implement it. Yeah I still wake up in cold sweats about it....

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this should work. In one-to-one or many-to-one you have a primary key in first table and foreign key in second table.

Answer (score 0):

The mapping should work as you have defined the table column to join. But just one thing i am not sure as you defined all annotations over getter method, so will it work in the same manner.